# PHP Output Not Appearing in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, spotify

I have made some code to post the output of a PHP file showing the music I have been recently listening to on Spotify.

The HTML, CSS and JS (for the spotify.php file) are included in this [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/t77mjj0k/4/)

The JS within my index.php file is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_spotify() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://theobearman.com/cv/modules/spotify.php',
            data: {
                request: 'true'
            },
            success: function(reply) {
                $('.now-playing').html("" + reply + "");
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = get_spotify;
</script>
```

My issue is that the output of the .php file is not showing up under the 'Music' header on [my website](https://theobearman.com/cv/).

This was working a few days ago, so I'm not sure why it is not working now.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Theo.

Comment: Code never just stops working, a change has been made which caused this :) Are you getting any errors? if so, please include them in the question.

Comment: None that I can see.

Comment: Add ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); to the top of your php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  get_spotify();
});
```

instead of `window.onload = get_spotify`, which may run before the element is rendered on the page.

Comment: Also, what is `text/rocketscript`, and why aren't you using `text/javascript`? Could be related to that too.

Comment: Cloudflare. Server side is still `text/javascript`.

Comment: I found the problem... you later overwrite window.onload with another function (something about elevator). Anyway, the code in my answer solves that problem too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `$(document).ready()` to call your function instead of `window.onload = ...` this ensures that jQuery has correctly been loaded.

Example: `$(document).ready(get_spotify);`

Answer (score 0):

I visited your site and everythings seems to be fine, only problem is that your function is not gettng called, I tried it from console and works perfectly

Comment: How do I call the function then?

Comment: I think window.onload = get_spotify not working correctly might be $(document).ready() will solve your problem.
after trying from console I can see "I last listened to 6 AM by J Balvin 23 minutes ago on Spotify."

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at your website code I found the problem.
You can have only **one** window.onload in one page but you have two of them so that's why it is not working.
Here is code of your first window.onload, put the get_spotify in here:

```
window.onload = function() {
  get_spotify();//INSERT HERE
  var elevator = new Elevator({
    element: document.querySelector('.elevator-button'),
    mainAudio: 'https://www.theobearman.com/cv/music/elevator-music.mp3',
    endAudio: 'https://www.theobearman.com/cv/music/ding.mp3'
  });
```

And also put get_spotify function body and prototype above this onload call.